# Replicate chrome devtools network XHR in Python

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

Scraping a "JavaScript heavy" website I see that, on page load and clicks, requests are made to get data via an API. The thing is there's authentication with a token that expires... that token is accessible when inspecting a given request header. E.g.: 'authorization': 'User asfpgyjrmvodfgjcvdfoiIUDYA'

How can I access (in Python) the requests being made by the website just like in Chrome DevTools > 'Network' tab > XHR ??

I know this is close to what I want because the following steps work until step 5... :

1. Chrome DevTolls > Network > XHR
2. Right-click on the intended request
3. Copy > Copy as cURL(cmd)
4. Use the handy tool [curl.trillworks](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to convert into python requests code
5. Execute -> Expected response is returned.
6. When the token expires no result is returned anymore...
7. Refreshing the page generates a new token so if I repeat the steps 1-5 I get the result again

Another way to put my question is: How to replicate step 3 in Python?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, for a different website, Can someone pls. help with a solution (already tried searching extensively)